# iwork numbers and apple Swift language relation

Tags: iwork-numbers, iwork

Is there any way to write Microsoft office Excel macros like scripts for iWork numbers code using apple's Swift programming language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it looks like you can
https://majestysoftware.wordpress.com/2015/03/31/swift-scripting-part-1/
However it's not something Apple has made easy.

To automate the Mac desktop you usually would use apple script.
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202905

As of OSX 10.10 you can use JavaScript syntax to script the Mac. I think this is Apples Attempt to make scripting easier as Apple script can be a pain IMO.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/Introduction.html

Comment: Utilities and samples to aid in using Swift with the Scripting Bridge: [GitHub: tingraldi/SwiftScripting ](https://github.com/tingraldi/SwiftScripting)